# unity launcher recovery

Tags: launcher

I recently added cairo-dock which worked fine until I added a 2nd dock at the top left of the screen.  Since then, my computer has consistently reported system errors.  How do I get the unity launcher back?  I've have clicked "remove" for the cairo dock in the software section; it tells me it is removed, but yet it remains.  Feels a bit like "Hal" from 2001.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the software has indeed been removed then "log out" and back in. This should start a new session. If then you don't have the "Unity" ......Ctrl+Alt+F2 then log in and type this `unity --replace`  now Ctrl+Alt+F7 and return to your desktop.